# How to print ê and other special characters available in ascii in Python for windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, ascii

I would like to print an ê in Python for windows. When I am at the DOS prompt I can type alt+136 to get an ê, however when I try to do this in python for DOS (code page cp437 or after chcp 1252 to cp1252) I can't type alt+136 to get the ê character. Why is this?

`print(chr(136))` correctly prints ê under code page cp437, but how can I open a unicode file with these characters:

```
Sokalâ€™, Lâ€™vivsâ€™ka Oblastâ€
BucureÅŸti, Romania
à¸‡'âŒ£'
```

and get it to print those characters instead of the below gobbledygook:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> f = codecs.open("unicode.txt", "r", "utf-8")
>>> f.read()
u"Sokal\xe2\u20ac\u2122, L\xe2\u20ac\u2122vivs\xe2\u20ac\u2122ka Oblast\xe2\u20ac\nBucure\xc5\u0178ti, Romania\n\xe0\xb8\u2021'\
xe2\u0152\xa3'\nThis text should be in \xe2\u20ac\u0153quotes\xe2\u20ac\\x9d.\nBroken text&hellip; it&#x2019;s ?ubberi?c!"
```

or even worse:

```
>>> f = codecs.open("unicode.txt", "r", "utf-8")
>>> print(f.read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 6-7: character maps to <undefined>
```

The following

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open("unicode.txt", "r", "utf-8")
s = f.read()
print(s.encode('utf8'))
```

prints

```
Sokal├óΓé¼Γäó, L├óΓé¼Γäóvivs├óΓé¼Γäóka Oblast├óΓé¼
Bucure├à┼╕ti, Romania
├á┬╕ΓÇí'├ó┼Æ┬ú'
This text should be in ├óΓé¼┼ôquotes├óΓé¼\x9d.
Broken text&hellip; it&#x2019;s ?ubberi?c!
```

instead of

```
Sokalâ€™, Lâ€™vivsâ€™ka Oblastâ€
BucureÅŸti, Romania
à¸‡'âŒ£'
```

I'm using:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

Is there some way of replacing the ê, etc. in the unicode string to rather be the printable ascii version of ê aka `chr(136)`?

Note that my question relates to how I can create a new non-Unicode extended ascii string based on the original UTF-8 unicode that will change the non-printable characters to characters in the ascii code page if there are equivalent characters available, or to replace the character with a ? or something similar if an equivalent is available.

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: Your character is not ascii... You may read about that here : http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-does-unicodeerror-ascii-decoding-encoding-error-ordinal-not-in-range-128-mean.htm

Comment: That's exactly the question. How can I change the unicode characters to characters that are printable in ascii? So replace \xe2 with â in some way.

Comment: unicode(s, "ascii") gives TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported, so Richard's comment doesn't help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console)

Comment: the last paragraph (recent edit) has many misconceptions. There are two string type in Python 2: `str` and `unicode`. What is your input? (if you don't know; run `type(your_input_string)`). If the input is a file then what its text character encoding (if you think it is not necessary to know the character encoding; read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)). What is the desired result? (another file or you just want to display them in the console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple questions, you've stumbled upon several common Unicode issues:

- how to type `ê`? -- [Alt+136 should work for `cp437`. Try Alt+234 for `cp1252` (not tested)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/type-and-display-accents-and-diacritical-marks):

  ```
  >>> u'ê'.encode('cp437')
  b'\x88'
  >>> int('88', 16)
  136
  >>> u'ê'.encode('cp1252')
  b'\xea'
  >>> int('ea', 16)
  234
  ```
- [how to print Unicode to Windows console in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/4279) How to fix `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' ...` exception? -- [follow the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/4279)
- why do you get [mojibake](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheAskObamaTweetWasGarbledOnScreenKnowYourUTF8UnicodeASCIIAndANSIDecodingMrPresident.aspx) if you read text from a file? -- don't print bytes from the file, convert to Unicode first: `io.open('unicode.txt', encoding=encoding).read()`
- why does Python console display `u'\u20ac'` instead of `€`? And in reverse, how to display `ê` Unicode character using only ascii printable characters e.g., `u'\xea'`? -- Python REPL uses `sys.displayhook()` (customizable) function to display the result of Python expression. It calls [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) e.g.:

  ```
  >>> print u'ê'
  ê
  >>> print repr(u'ê')
  u'\xea'
  >>> u'ê'
  u'\xea'
  ```

  `u'\xea'` is a text representation of the corresponding Unicode string. You can use it as a Unicode string literal, to create the string in Python source code.

It might not be necessary in your case but in general to input/display arbitrary Unicode characters in Windows console, you could [install `win-unicode-console` package](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console).

---

Unrelated: `print(chr(136))` is incorrect. It will produce wrong output if the environment uses an incompatible to yours character encoding e.g.:

```
>>> print chr(136)
�
```

Print Unicode instead:

```
>>> print unichr(234)
ê
```

The reason is that `chr()` returns a bytestring on Python 2. The same byte may represent different characters in different character encodings that is why you should always use Unicode if you work with text.

Answer (score -1):

You decoded it from utf8 when you read it, so you need to encode it when you write it (back to utf8, or to some other codec)

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open("unicode.txt", "r", "utf-8")
s = f.read()
print(s.encode('utf8'))
```